# How to upgrade all libraries in an old react native project?

Tags: react-native, dependencies, npm-install, upgrade

I have some experience in react native but I am relatively new to the field. I have cloned a react native project but it is very old and it contains a lot of libraries that are also either depricated or conflicting. I want to make the project compile as its not compiling now too because of the conflicting library issues. Any help or guidance regarding what i should do to make it work?

I have tried a number of things like deleting node modules and package-lock and running npm install but it doesnt run so I used --force but it still didnt make it work then I used npm install --legacy-peer-deps and it still didnt work.
i tried to upgrade the specific libraries that were mentioned in the errors but they also failed.

right now I have no idea what should be done.

Answer (score 5):

As of npm version 5.2.0+, we can update all our dependencies without installing any additional packages.

Run the command in the root of your project:

`npx npm-check-updates -u && npm i`

"npx npm-check-updates -u" the command just updates the package.json that’s why we need tonpm i after the update the package.json.

for more info [click here](https://freakycoder.com/react-native-notes-12-how-to-update-all-dependencies-at-once-f73dcd65642)

Comment: saved me hours. Could  resolve broken dependency tree issue with this

Comment: This works!! I have copied all the dependencies from old project added them into new project then run this 'npx npm-check-updates -u' command